# How to return NA when converting string with leading/trailing whitespace to date in R

Tags: r, string, date

Is there a simple way to return an `NA` when converting a string with a leading/trailing whitespace to date when the leading/trailing whitespace isn't in the format parameter? You'd think that would be the default case.

```
# Converts date as expected
as.Date("20180101", format = "%Y%m%d")
# Still converts date, but wanting and expecting to return an NA
as.Date(" 20180101", format = "%Y%m%d")
```

Comment: At least the handling of _trailing_ whitespace is documented in `?as.Date`: "Character strings are processed as far as necessary for the format specified: any trailing characters are ignored". `as.Date("2018-12-13 This is ignored")`

Answer (score 0):

We can replace the leading space with a letter and it would return `NA`

```
as.Date(sub("^ ", "T", " 20180101"), format = "%Y%m%d")
#[1] NA
```

---

Or use `chartr` for replacing

```
as.Date(chartr(" ", "T", " 20180101"), format = "%Y%m%d")
#[1] NA
```

---

Or create a function that checks whether there is a `trailing/leading` space and set it to `NA` before doing the `Date` class conversion

```
dateWithTrailingLeadingSpace <- function(date, format) {
        i1 <- grepl("^ | $", date)
        date[i1] <- NA
     as.Date(date, format = format)
   }

dateWithTrailingLeadingSpace(c(" 20180101", "20180101", "20180101 "), 
        format = "%Y%m%d")
#[1] NA           "2018-01-01" NA
```

Comment: Thanks. It's weird my question needs such a workaround